# Sharing storage on Linux and Solaris

Tags: filesystems, hpc, nas, san

I'm looking for a solution in order to share a san mounted volume between several hosts running on Linux (RHEL) and/or Solaris (Sparc).

Note that I basically need to share a set of directories containing large binary files that are accessed in random R/W mode.

I have the following reqs :

- keep the data on the SAN
- suitable i/o performances as the software is pretty demanding on IOPS
- stick to a shared file system as I can't afford a cluster fs (lack of MDS/OSS infrastructure)
- compression could be really usefull

For now I've found only the following candidates :

- GFS2 , supports Linux only, no compression
- VxFS , supports Linux and Solaris, compression supported

So if you have some suggestions for this list, I'll really welcome them.

Thanks in advance,